# Data validation on models (ASP.NET Core 6)

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

For some reason, I cannot get error message in browser which I define on my models.

Here is my code - controller:

```
using ACS.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace ACS.Controllers
{
    public class MAWBController : Controller
    {
        public static List<Models.Shipment> listaMAWB = new List<Shipment>();

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult InsertMAWB()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult InsertMAWB(Shipment model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                listaMAWB.Add(model);
                return RedirectToAction("ShowListMAWB");
            }
            else
            {
                return View(model);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Model class:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ACS.Models
{
    public class Shipment
    {
        public DateTime ArrivalDate { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Field MAWB is mandatory!")]
        public int MAWB { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model ACS.Models.Shipment

<form asp-action="InsertMAWB" method="post">

    <label asp-for="MAWB"></label>
    <input asp-for="MAWB" />
    <span asp-validation-for="MAWB" class="text-danger">

    </span>

    <button type="submit">Save</button>


</form>
```

For some reason, if I enter nothing into a field, I get the error

> The value '' is invalid

instead of the error msg which I defined on the model - any suggestions as to why?

Thank you - I'm a newbie in C#

I try to debug and I "catch" that line goes on "else" block instead of "if" block which is correct because I did not enter any data...

Comment: try changing the datatype of `MAWB` to nullable. So something like `public int? MAWB { get; set; }` this